# issue on starting of mysql

Tags: linux, mysql

I have installed "mysql-5.6.14-linux-glibc2.5-x86_64.tar.gz" in user specified directory. I tried to start the application, but it is saying "Starting MySQL..The server quit without updating PID file ([FAILED]al/mysql/data/localhost.localdomain.pid)." 
Then i checked in mysqldata/localhost.localdomain.err log :

```
 .
 .
  2013-10-15 00:29:01 22793 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
  2013-10-15 00:29:01 22793 [Note] IPv6 is available.
  2013-10-15 00:29:01 22793 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
  2013-10-15 00:29:01 22793 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
  2013-10-15 00:29:01 22793 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist
```

can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Initiating location will solve your issue 
`mysql_install_db --user=mysql --ldata=[destination]` refer [this](http://will-bloggs-too.com/2011/11/29/mysql-error-cant-open-and-lock-privilege-tables-table-doesnt-exist/). Also provide mysql ownership and group privileges with `chown -R mysql /var/lib/mysql` and `chgrp -R mysql /var/lib/mysql`.Never forget to restart mysql service after updating configurations.

To set base directory. check the path by issuing commands `which mysql_install_db` and `which my_print_defaults`. Pass that path with `--basedir=/your path`. This is well explained with an example in this [blog](http://blog.ijun.org/2011/02/mysqlinstalldb-fatal-error-could-not.html) post

Comment: when i execute mysql_install_db --user=mysql --ldata=[destination] i got error like .."FATAL ERROR: Could not find ./bin/my_print_defaults".

Comment: Please check [this](http://blog.ijun.org/2011/02/mysqlinstalldb-fatal-error-could-not.html) and set your base directory.

Comment: @RenjuChandranchingath, `mysql_install_db` doesn't exist for Windows Servers though.... is there a solution for Windows?